# quickblox special update operators for custom objects rest api

Tags: quickblox

Does any one tried to use special update operators in Quickblox for custom objects in docs at

[Custom object documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects)

there are few examples provided but none of them are working when typed in terminal. For example when i try to remove element from answers array in my `InvitationStore` custom object with id `56165731a28f9af6df000236` and session token `d536d482c4637beb8fef79eeb8d45c0473dae9aa` i type following command in terminal

```
curl -X PUT -H "QB-Token: d536d482c4637beb8fef79eeb8d45c0473dae9aa" 
-d "pop[answers]=1" https://api.quickblox.com/data/InvitationStore/56165731a28f9af6df000236.json
```

but it makes no effect in response i receive custom object with same structure as before operation.Id and session token are correct because when using standard operation for example seting answers array to value [@"YES" ,@"NO"] it works and the structure does change it only takes no effect for special update operators.
I work on starter plan so question is is this functionality not available  in my current plan(can't find it in docs) or is it something wrong with my code or is it Quickblox error?